# Xpath get distinct child nodes name that the name count is mor then one

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How i can get via Xpath distinct child nodes name that the name mached mor than one time?

if these ish the xml:

```
> <el>
>     <name1></name1>
>     <name1></name1>
>     <name1></name1>
>     <name2></name2>
>     <name1></name1>
>     <name2></name2>
>     <name2></name2>
>     <name3></name3> </el>
```

the result:

name1
name2

not the name3

Comment: Please fix your question. Think of a proper title and write at least one complete paragraph of text that describes what what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grouping by checking along the sibling axis shows quadratic (slow) behaviour, when grouping in xslt 1 it's almost always a good idea to use a key (known as Muenchian grouping)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="el">
 <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('n',name())[2])]">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="n" match="*" use="name()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're right, that clearly outperforms my solution on larger nodesets

Answer (score 0):

```
./*[preceding-sibling::node()/name(.) != name(.)]
   [following-sibling::node()/name(.) = name(.)]/name(.)
```

This finds all child nodes which don't have a preceding sibling of the same name (distinct names), but do have a following sibling with the same name (more than one)

Comment: These throw xpath exception  invalid tokin

Comment: @Oldi88 The syntax is valid xpath2 not xpath1 (but in xslt2 it would be more efficient to use xsl:for-each-group)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You're right. I wasn't aware of this being also an XSLT question...

Comment: @LukasEder the qustion is not very clear:-) but it is tagged xslt so I assumed it was in that setting, but who knows:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yeah, who knows :)